# How to search for files using glob then iterate over those files to search for a specific string in Python

Tags: python, bash, loops

I want to basically convert the bash shell script I have below into Python. Would anyone have an idea how I would be able to accomplish this please?

```
currentdir=`pwd`
find $currentdir -type f -exec grep -r 'host:' {} \; > GOODtest.txt
```

I almost have it in Python below: but I can't figure out how to get it to iterate over the list of files it found using glob. The code below only iterates over one file and stops

```
 import glob
 import re

 for name in glob.glob('*ssh_time'):
   strings=['host:']
   output=[]
   #print name
   myvar = name
   print myvar
   with open(myvar, 'rb+') as f:
     for line in f.readlines():
        for subs in strings:
            if subs in line:
                output.append(line)
 print(output)
```

Comment: first things first, is your glob returning anything?

Comment: I notice in one location you write `print myvar`, and at the bottom you write `print(output)`.  The first call is python2 syntax, the second is python3.  Also, do you realize that `glob.glob` is not recursive?

Comment: Did you try os.walk? https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk or https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Yes thanks tried it, but it didn't seem to help in this case

Comment: Have a look to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756760/8418376 -- it shows the basic principle of directory/file walking and processing.